# Where to place network.lic when installing MATLAB 2021a with Packer?

Tags: matlab, packer

When installing Matlab 2021a with packer, I also define network.lic as license servers. I wonder where should I put network.lic so that Matlab registers network.lic?

Now I put it in `C:\TEMP\Matlab-R2021a\network.lic` and define it in `matlab_installer_input.txt` as `licensePath=C:\TEMP\Matlab-R2021a\network.lic`.

Then use it as:

```
Start-Process -FilePath ".\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "-inputFile matlab_installer_input.txt" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

I know I have problems with it because when I go to the VM locally on Activate Matlab 2021a and load the network.lic everything works ok, but when I do the packer installation and try to start the Matlab process hangs indefinitely.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Show us the packer configuration file